# get_<field>_display in django templates with filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
from djano.contrib.auth.models import User
class Person(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
            ('M','Male'),
            ('F','Female'),
            )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    to_be_listed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20000, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
person_data = Person.objects.filter(user__in=[1,2,3]).values('gender','description', 'to_be_listed')
```

Now in templates i want to show person_data and when I am writing {{person_data.0.gender}} it is showing me 'm' or 'f' but I want it to be displayed as male of female.

I also tried get_gender_display  but it works only with model_obj not with valueQueryset.

Suggest me a better way to fetch gender(as male or female) in templates.

Comment: Why do you use `values()` for such cheap query?

Comment: @catavaran  it is just a sample code, there are many others things in values and models.

Comment: The problem is that there is no easy way of replacing `get_FOO_display()` in the list of dicts.  You have to create custom template filter or add `gender_display` key to the dicts in the view. So if you can use plain `QuerySet` then use it. If you call `values()` for performance reasons then the `only()` call is the good alternative for it.